# Python3 print string formatting

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

Is it recommend to format a string :

```
var = 'python 3'
print(f"This is {var}") # prints out This is python 3
```

or

```
var = 'python 3'
print("This is", var)
```

or the old string formatting

```
var = 'python 3'
print("This is %s" % var)
```

Also, is `print(f"{var}")` a new feature to python 3.6? I got `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` when running the same code in python 3.5.3.

Comment: Yes, [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) are new in 3.6

Comment: *"is [it] a new feature to python 3.6?"* - [yes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals).

Comment: When I run it with [online compiler](https://repl.it/languages/python3) in 3.5.2, the output prints without an error so I was confused.

Comment: The main use for f strings I've found so far is it makes __str__ returns in classes much cleaner.

Comment: @Ricek It's actually funny. The online Python interpreter prints a wrong version of the interpreter. Check that with `sys.version`. It's 3.6.1. You may report that to the website maintainers.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it recommended ...

No one is enforcing anything. Choose whatever option you prefer (the second print isn't actually formatting, it is simply passing more args to print).

`f`-strings were introduced to tackle some shortcomings of the other formatting approaches (See [Rational of PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#rationale)), if you find the other approaches work fine, there's no immediate need to switch.

> is `print(f"{var}")` a new feature to python 3.6

Yes, `f`-strings are Python `>= 3.6`.

Answer (score 0):

if your looking for something to tell you best formatting practices try using a style guide like pep8
`print("This is {:s}".format(var)`
refer to it here https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/